# jQuery: Calculate Image Map area size and show div in the middle

Tags: jquery, html, dictionary

I need to show div while Image Map area hover (something like tooltip ).

That's ok, but the problem is that I need to show div on the middle of each area, which are in different shapes and sizes. I don't want to use any tooltip plugin, as the content of it should be easy to change.

The jsfiddle is in comment.

I don't have deep knowledges of jQuery, that's why I need you help for that)) Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/frontDev111/69ostk40/

Comment: You could try and implement it like this. http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/4eFF3/

Comment: I think this will not help,as I need to put button or inputs in tooltip, that is not possible in title.Thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly , you have an image map where you want to put a pointer to the center .

Try this

```
var width = jQuery("#imageMaps").attr("width");
var height = jQuery("#imageMaps").attr("height");

var width = width / 2;
var height = height / 2;

var Point =  jQuery("#div to position").style("margin-top",height);
var Point =  jQuery("#div to position").style("margin-left",width);
```

I assume you have the same div is the pointer to the image maps.

Comment: hmm I think I misunderstood you(( I need to show .tooltip whole hovering each area, and show that div in the middle of each area.When I try this I get error as haven't use any width height attr

Comment: ahh now it's clear what you need to do , try this , it is very similar to what you have to do , just change the photos :

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

Comment: Thanks, I think this can help, btw I need to have buttons, inputs,etc.. in tooltip div, couldn't do this with this plugin

Comment: When you call the event click to open text box and and you can still do all the tooltip of the case since you have all the details , maybe you can do it , I have not looked at the bottom of the plugin that I showed you , but maybe it works .